# box-shadow on ::selection pseudo-element

Tags: html, css

Is there a way to add a box-shadow to the ::selection pseudo-element?

```
*::selection {
  box-shadow: 2px 2px black;
}
```

seems not to be working.

Comment: Strange the CSS does seem to stop you from highlighting the link http://jsfiddle.net/kqteD/

Comment: @PhilipK: That's what happens when you attempt to define a style rule for `::selection`. The text is still being highlighted, but the browser no longer paints the default highlight style.

Comment: oh I see it defaults to background-color:none;

Answer (score 4):

I don't believe you can add a box-shadow to `::selection {}`.

It accepts: `background-color`, `color` and `text-shadow`.

For example:

```
::selection {
    background-color: black;
    color: white;
    text-shadow: 0 0 8px red;
}
```

Comment: Yes, I had the same results... So there seems to be no other solution I guess. :(